# Xcode - How to create a simple objective-c application using a project template?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I want to create a new project in Xcode (4.2), but I don't need any fancy windows or iOs templates, just a simple, standalone project (with an auto-generated main() perhaps) where I can build some classes and run simple tests.

Is the `Cocoa Application` template under `Mac OS X` the most suitable for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just a simple, no-ui console app for testing classes, just go with `Console Application`. It has `main.m`, and very little else. If you want something completely empty, however, under the `Other` category for templates, there's one called `Empty`.

Comment: I don't see `Console Application`, I see `Cocoa Application`, is that what you meant?

Comment: Look for something mentioning `Console` or `Command Line Tool` - it may not be in the same category as `Cocoa Application`. I'm running XCode 4.2 and it's in the `Applications` category, along with `Cocoa Application` and `Cocoa-Applescript Application`.

Comment: I see that now, but in the project Type selection, objective-c is not listed...which type allows me to code in obj-c?

Comment: `Foundation/Core Foundation/Core Services/Core Data` will allow you to use Objective-C. `C/C++` would too, technically, but it would take some more work to get it to play nice. Go with the default `Foundation`. Those choices are actually just asking how the project is initially set up. You can blend Obj-C, C, and C++ as you need it but there are some caveats. If you are just learning, stick with basic `Foundation`

Comment: That worked, a little confusing for an Xcode newbie...thanks!

Comment: It is an exceptionally rare project type for *most* developers to use (even if it is a great way to learn the basics of the language).

Comment: @bbum Probably because most folks just dive into iOs ui development...I'm starting out with obj-c first to learn the basics.

Comment: Great place to start,  assuredly.   I would encourage you to start with a single-window GUI application, though.  You can still learn all the basics (excellent -- the # of questions on here where folks missed the basics is staggering) while also being able to throw a simple button / text field in for interacting with your code.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa Application will create a project with the Application menu only… maybe it's what you need.